# Permission denied when trying to copy files

Tags: python, ubuntu, shutil

Using the script:

```
    file = os.path.join(subfolder_name, list_of_files[i])
    for dest_folder_finetune, dest_folder_relab in zip(finetune_datasets, relab_datasets):
        copy(file, dest_folder_finetune)
        copy(file, dest_folder_relab)
```

every 20 iterations, I am having a permission denied problem. The stack, looks something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/revan/boosting_classifier_with_games/dataset_creator.py", line 72, in <module>
main()
  File "/home/revan/boosting_classifier_with_games/dataset_creator.py", line 24, in main
create_test_and_relab(list_of_subfolders)
  File "/home/revan/boosting_classifier_with_games/dataset_creator.py", line 66, in create_test_and_relab
copy(file, dest_folder_finetune)
  File "/home/revan/anaconda2/envs/pytorch/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/home/revan/anaconda2/envs/pytorch/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sun_btbivuchmkkzetpo.jpg'
```

The 'funny' thing is that I definitely have all permissions for that file. Furthermore, I tried to copy it manually, and I can do it without problem. If I randomize the process, the same file gets copied, but then some other file (after 20 iterations) cannot be copied.

PS: Changing copy to copy2, gives the exact same problem.

Has anyone experienced anything similar in the past? Could it be a Python or a Linux problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a file called `sun_btbivuchmkkzetpo.jpg` in the **root directory of your filesystem**?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I am getting the names of the files by running a script that iterates over the subfolders. Then I copy files using the names from that list, but every 20 copies, it gives this problem. Thing is, 20 is nothing special in here (there are 100 files for subfolder), and I manually checked that the file exists, in addition to having read/write permissions and being able to manually copy it.

Comment: You do appreciate that storing random data in the **root directory of your filesystem** is, erm ... a rather dodgy and unadvisable thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

One of your datasets has a bad folder name, which is setting the destination to the root of the file system.

To just get it working, you can skip when it's trying to copy to the root:

```
import os 
file = os.path.join(subfolder_name, list_of_files[i])
for dest_folder_finetune, dest_folder_relab in zip(finetune_datasets, relab_datasets):
        if os.path.abspath(dest_folder_finetune) != "/":
            copy(file, dest_folder_finetune)
        else: 
            print("Warning, path {} for dest_folder_finetune writes to the root of the filesystem".format(dest_folder_finetune))
        if os.path.abspath(dest_folder_relab) != "/":
            copy(file, dest_folder_relab)
        else: 
            print("Warning, path {} for dest_folder_relab writes to the root of the filesystem".format(dest_folder_relab ))
```

However, if this is more than a live once script, I suggest scrubbing and verifying the dataset beforehand instead.

Answer (score -4):

try with "sudo python filename.py"

Comment: Brute-forcing it with `sudo` rather than understanding the problem and fixing it, doesn't seem like very good advice.